# Workbook.close causes sub to exit

Tags: excel, vba, plugins

I have a set of versioned Excel documents that I am trying to get to auto-update when there is a new version available.  What fails is that the `.close` method is not just closing one of the workbooks but also exiting the sub.

The process:
The sub gets called from Worksheet_Activate and immediately checks to see if an upgrade is needed. If needed, it collects all of the names of the sheets (except the "Count" sheet which is a copy from a template), creates a new workbook with the same sheets as the old one, copies the data over to the proper sheets, closes the old workbook, deletes the old workbook, saves the new workbook with the same name as the old workbook.

Pretty straight forward and it worked great until it didn't.  I'm not sure why, but now when the `wkbFrom.Close` command is executed it also exits the procedure.

I've been digging around and the only answer I could find that seemed to address my issue was to give some delay before/after the close so that Excel will have time to finish and not collide with itself.  So I tried putting in a 5 second delay before the close command but to no avail.

Excel doesn't crash, it's still up and running properly.  I checked the Event Viewer and Excel is not throwing any errors.  The sub simply closes the workbook and then exits the sub.

Here is the full code for the sub.

```
    Sub UpgradeHWWorkbook(Optional HWSheetVersion As Double)

'--------------------------------
'This sub upgrades a hardware tracking
'workbook to the newest version based on
'version in the variable HWSheetVersion
'--------------------------------

'Before anything else, Check to see if upgrade is needed.
'If sheet version is equal or larger than the plugin version
'OR the name of the sheet is wrong, exit without upgrading
'---------------------------------------------------------------------
    If HWSheetVersion >= HWPlugInVersion Or _
        Not ActiveSheet.CodeName Like "BaseHWSheet_*" Then
            Exit Sub
    End If
'---------------------------------------------------------------------

'VAR declarations----------------
    Dim wkbFrom As Workbook         'Holds the original workbook
    Dim wkbTo As Workbook           'Holds the new workbook
    Dim sWKB As Workbook            'Holds Workbook where Count sheet is kept
    Dim sWKS As Worksheet           'Holds Count sheet
    Dim wks As Worksheet            'Holds worksheets
    Dim wksNames() As String        'Holds the names of all the worksheets
    Dim wkbFromName As String       'Holds the name of the original workbook
    Dim wkbFromPath As String       'Holds the path of the original workbook
    Dim wkbToPath As String         'Holds the path where the new workbook will be saved
    Dim rng As String               'Holds the range of cells that will be copied
    Dim x As Byte                   'Holds counter
    Dim wksName As Variant          'Holds the name of the current worksheet
'--------------------------------

'Sub Settings--------------------
    Set wkbFrom = ActiveWorkbook                                    'Set the active workbook as the one that the data comes from
    wkbFromPath = wkbFrom.Path                                      'Grabs the path of the original workbook
    wkbFromName = wkbFrom.Name                                      'Grab the original workbook name
    wkbToPath = wkbFrom.FullName                                    'Grab the path path and name in another var so we don't have to do it by hand
    ReDim wksNames(0)                                               'Starts off the array that will hold the worksheet names
    x = 0                                                           'Flush the counter
    rng = "A2:D18"                                                  'The range of cells that will be copied and pasted
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False                               'Turn off annoying pop-ups
    Set sWKB = Workbooks("StockroomAddins.xlam")                    'Workbook with Count sheet to copy to new workbook
    Set sWKS = sWKB.Worksheets("Count")                             'Count sheet to copy to new workbook
'--------------------------------


'Get all of the worksheet names (except Count) in the workbook
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    For Each wks In wkbFrom.Worksheets                              'itenerate through the book
        If Not wks.Name = "Count" Then                              'If the worksheet isn't the "Count" sheet...
            wksNames(x) = wks.Name                                  'add the sheet name to the array wksName()
            x = 1 + UBound(wksNames)                                'Increase the array by 1
            ReDim Preserve wksNames(x)                              'Increase the size of the array by 1
        End If
    Next wks
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------


'Create new workbook & add Count sheet
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set wkbTo = Workbooks.Add                                       'Create the new workbook
    wkbTo.Activate                                                  'Make sure new book is active book
    sWKS.Copy Before:=Sheets("Sheet1")                              'Add the Count sheet to workbook
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------

'Iterate through the sheets in the original workbook, add sheets with the same name to the new book, copy data from the old sheet to the new sheet
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    For Each wksName In wksNames                                    'Loop through all of the worksheet names and...
        If Not wksName = "" Then                                    'If it isn't blank...
            Call NewHardwareTrackingSheet(wksName, wkbTo)           'Call the sub that creates a new tracking sheet
            wkbFrom.Worksheets(wksName).Range(rng).Copy             'Copy the data from the old sheet
            wkbTo.Worksheets(wksName).Range(rng).PasteSpecial _
                Paste:=xlPasteValues                                'Paste the data (Values only) into the new sheet
        End If
    Next wksName
    
    wkbTo.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete                               'Delete the default "Sheet 1" that every new workbook has

    wkbFrom.Close Savechanges:=False                                'close the original workbook
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    
'Delete the old workbook and save the new one in the same place with the same name as the old one
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Kill wkbToPath                                                  'Kill the original
    wkbTo.SaveAs Filename:=wkbToPath, FileFormat:=52                'Save the new as the original
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True                                'Turn annoying pop-ups back on
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------

'Clean up-------------------------------------
Set wkbFrom = Nothing: Set wkbTo = Nothing: Set sWKB = Nothing
Set wks = Nothing: Set sWKS = Nothing
'---------------------------------------------
    

End Sub
```

Any ideas on what I've messed up?  I figured that since it worked at one point and now doesn't, that I've probably messed up the code somewhere but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Is the Workbook you are closing the one containing the code?

Comment: `Set wkbFrom = ActiveWorkbook  ` If you close the ActivrWorkbook, yes, the sub will end. That's the normal behaviour, actually

Comment: @firefox if you close _ThisWorkbook_ code will stop.  If you close _ActiveWorkbook_ and it is also ThisWorkbook, then code stops, otherwise code continues

Comment: @chrisneilsen No, the code is in a plugin.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I'm not seeing where I set `wkbFrom = ActiveWorkbook`.  I see that I set `wkbTo.Activate`.  I had tested it with wkbFrom being both active and inactive and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found my answer and I feel a bit stupid about it.  Thanks to the folks who asked me some questions because they caused the thought process that worked.

It seems that the spreadsheet I was using to test the code must have gotten corrupted.  I tried it on a couple of other files and it worked correctly.  No wonder I couldn't find a code issue: there isn't one.

Goes to show the old adage "Measure twice, cut once."  I should have tested on multiple files and not assumed my single test file was right.

Much thanks to those who read, thought about, and commented on my post.  It is appreciated.

EDIT: Or not......

Came in this morning and it's not working again.  There's got to be something in my code that is causing the issue on some and not on others.  TBH, I have no idea what it is.

This is really causing me to bang my head on the wall.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I think I've figured this out.

I am calling this Sub to check the version each time a sheet is activated with this:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Activate()
   Application.Run "StockroomBarcodeSheets.UpgradeHWWorkbook", HWSheetVersion
End Sub
```

To do some other testing, I set up another sub inside my plug-in that just called the UpgradeHWWorkbook sub with a fake HWSheetVersion so I could force a workbook to upgrade.  Lo, and behold, this setup worked perfectly every time.

So, when I call from the Worksheet_Activate() it exits on the `.close` command.  When I call it from a sub inside the add-in, it works perfectly.

Because the UpgradeHWWorkbook is in a plug-in I thought that the restriction upon closing the calling workbook wouldn't come into affect.  I was wrong.